# What is the best way to create a new list from an old one but with objects from that list that do not have the same reference

Tags: java

For example let's say i have a Class MyObject

```
class MyObject{
int i;
String s;

My(int i,String s){
    this.i = i;
    this.s = s;
}
...
setters/getters/toString
}
```

and that i have a list with objects of that Class(i dont know if that make a different what kind of list it is but i want this to work with ObservableList)

```
ObservableList<MyObject> listOne = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
MyObject one = new MyObject(1,"foo");
MyObject two = new MyObject(2,"boo");
```

Now i want to make new ObservableList from objects of listOne but i want that new list have objects with different reference

if i make it like this

```
ObservableList<MyObject>listTwo=FXCollections.observableArrayList(listOne);
```

when i do something like this

```
listOne.get(0).setI(500);
```

It will also effect object in listTwo

What is best practice to avoid this ? How can i make new list of some list with objects of that list which are treat as different objects ?

I could do something like this

```
for (MyObject object : listOne) {
        MyObject cloneObject = new MyObject(object.getI(),object.getS());
        listTwo.add(cloneObject);
}
```

I just hope that there is a better way

Comment: This is typically referred to as a "deep copy" btw.

Comment: The better way would probably be to use immutable objects, to be able to share the same objects without any problem. But with mutable objects, then what you have is basically the only way. Of course you could make a copy constructor, but the principle is the same.